# Increase table width after print not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I know this kind of question has been asked before. But i am stuck and tried everything. I have no clue how to fix this. 
Heres the issue: the printed table format and display format of the details has less width and the values are not displayed properly. Please help.

**View page to be printed**
[image: View page to be printed]

**print preview after clicking print button**

[image: print preview after clicking print button]

Here is my what i have done so far:

**html file:**

```
      <div class="card-body collapse in">
            <div class="card-block big-font" id="print_content">
            <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading"  style="padding-bottom:15px;padding-top:15px;"><b>Client</b></div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <br>
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <td id="c_name"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <td id="c_add"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Contact No</th>
                        <td id="c_contact"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Client GST</th>
                        <td id="c_gst"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Pending Amount</th>
                        <td id="c_pen"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <br>
                </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" style="padding-bottom:15px;padding-top:15px;"><b>Purchase History</b></div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                        <table class="table" id="p_history" >
                         </table>                         
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 no-print" style="text-align: center;">
                     <div id="printbtn" name="printbtn">
                     </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**js**

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function()    
{
$('#clientnames').change(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault;
    var client_id = $('#clientnames').val();
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "<?php echo base_url().'clients/get_client_info'; ?>",
        data: {client_id: client_id},
        success: function(res)   
        {                   
           var parsed = JSON.parse(res);                   
           $("#p_history tr").remove();
            if(parsed.status_code == 1) 
            {
                var dash = '-';
                var i;                        
                $('#client-tab').show();
                $('#c_name').html(parsed.info['client_name']);
                $('#c_add').html(parsed.info['client_address']);
                $('#c_contact').html(parsed.info['client_phone']);
                $('#c_gst').html(parsed.info['client_gst']);

                if(parsed.balance == null || parsed.balance == 0)   
                {$('#c_pen').html('-');}
                else   
                { $('#c_pen').html(parsed.balance); }

                var purchase = parsed.purchase;
                var bills = parsed.bills;
                //console.log(purchase);
                //console.log(bills);
                document.getElementById('printbtn').innerHTML = " ";
                document.getElementById('p_history').innerHTML = " ";
                if(bills.length != null || bills.length != 0)
                {                            
                    $('#p_history').append('<th>Bill No</th><th> SGST</th><th> CGST</th><th>Total</th><th> Pending</th><th>Details</th>');

                    for( var i=0; i< bills.length; i++)   
                    {
                        var prodobj = parsed.purchase[i]; 
                        var billobj = parsed.bills[i]; 
                        var p = null; var hsn = null; var h =null; var w = null;var r =null; var a = null;
                        bid = billobj['bill_id'];
                        var pending = '-'; 
                        if(billobj['bill_pending'] != 0 ){ pending = billobj['bill_pending'] ;}

                        $('#p_history').append('<tr><td>' + billobj['bill_no'] + '<div id="div'+i+'" class="collapse changethis">\
                                <div class="panel-body" float="right" id="print_content">\
                                <table class="table details" style="margin-right: -390px;margin-top:20px;" id="'+bid+'">\
                                <th  class="prodname" colspan="">Product name</th>\
                                <th>HSN Code</th>\
                                <th>Height</th>\
                                <th>Width</th>\
                                <th>Rate</th>\
                                <th>Quantity</th>\
                                <th>Amount</th>\
                                <tr></tr>\
                                </table>\
                                </div> \
                                </div> </td><td>' + billobj['sgst'] + '</td><td>' + billobj['cgst'] + '</td><td>'+billobj['bill_grandtotal'] +'</td><td>'+ pending +'</td><td><a href="#div'+i+'" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" vertical-align: middle;>+</a></td></tr>');                    

                         for(var j=0;j<purchase.length; j++)
                        {
                            if(billobj['bill_id'] == purchase[j]['bid'])
                            {
                                var a = '<td id="t">'+purchase[j]['product_name']+'</td><td>'+purchase[j]['hsncode']+'</td><td>'+purchase[j]['hsncode']+'</td><td>'+purchase[j]['height']+'</td><td>'+purchase[j]['width']+'</td><td>'+purchase[j]['width']+'</td><td>'+purchase[j]['rate']+'</td><td>'+purchase[j]['qty']+'</td><td>'+purchase[j]['amt']+'</td>';
                                var mh,mw;
                                var x = purchase[j]['bid'];
                                var m1 = purchase[j]['m1']; 
                                var m2 = purchase[j]['m2']; 
                                if(m1 == 1 && m2==1){ mh="ft";mw="ft"}
                                if(m1 == 2 && m2==2){ mh="inches";mw="inches"}
                                if(m1 == 3 && m2==3){ mh="cm";mw="cm"}
                                if(m1 == 4 && m2==4){ mh="mm";mw="mm"}
                                var table = document.getElementById(x);
                                // Create an empty <tr> element and add it to the 1st position of the table:
                                var row = table.insertRow(1);
                                // Insert new cells (<td> elements) at the 1st and 2nd position of the "new" <tr> element:
                                var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                                var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                                var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
                                var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
                                var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
                                var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
                                var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);                               
                                // Add some text to the new cells:
                                cell1.innerHTML = purchase[j]['product_name'];
                                cell2.innerHTML = purchase[j]['hsncode'];
                                cell3.innerHTML = purchase[j]['height']+" "+mh;
                                cell4.innerHTML = purchase[j]['width']+" "+mw;
                                cell5.innerHTML = purchase[j]['rate'];
                                cell6.innerHTML = purchase[j]['qty'];
                                cell7.innerHTML = purchase[j]['amt'];
                            }                            
                        }  
                    }

                $('#printbtn').append('<br><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" onClick="print_page()"> <i class="icon-print4" style="color:white;"></i> Print History</button>');                        
                } //bills exist
                if(bills.length == null || bills.length == 0)//if no bills
                {   $('#printbtn').html('<br> No History');  }                            
            } //endif status code is success
       }//end of success 
    });
 })
})
</script>
<script>
function print_page()
{
     var printContents = document.getElementById("print_content").innerHTML;
     var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
     document.getElementById("print_content").style.fontSize = "xx-large";
     document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
    //expand collapsible divs
     $('div.changethis').addClass('in').css("height", "");
     window.print();
     document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
     window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('clients/search'); ?>";   
}
</script>
```

**print.css**

```
@media print {
.content-body   
{
margin-left: -55%;
margin-top: -7%;
}
  [class*="col-sm-"] {
    /*float: left;*/
  }

  [class*="col-xs-"] {
   /* float: left;*/
  }
.print-col-3
    {
        width:100% !important;
            }

    .text-md-right{
        float:right;
    }
  .col-sm-12, .col-xs-12 {
    width:100% !important;
    float:left !important;
  }

  .col-sm-11, .col-xs-11 {
    width:91.66666667% !important;
  }

  .col-sm-10, .col-xs-10 {
    width:83.33333333% !important;
  }

  .col-sm-9, .col-xs-9 {
    width:75% !important;
  }

  .col-sm-8, .col-xs-8 {
    width:66.66666667% !important;
  }

  .col-sm-7, .col-xs-7 {
    width:58.33333333% !important;
  }

  .col-sm-6, .col-xs-6 {
    width:50% !important;
  }

  .col-sm-5, .col-xs-5 {
    width:41.66666667% !important;
  }

  .col-sm-4, .col-xs-4 {
    width:33.33333333% !important;
  }

  .col-sm-3, .col-xs-3 {
    width:25% !important;
  }

  .col-sm-2, .col-xs-2 {
    width:16.66666667% !important;
  }

  .col-sm-1, .col-xs-1 {
    width:8.33333333% !important;
  }

  .col-sm-1,
  .col-sm-2,
  .col-sm-3,
  .col-sm-4,
  .col-sm-5,
  .col-sm-6,
  .col-sm-7,
  .col-sm-8,
  .col-sm-9,
  .col-sm-10,
  .col-sm-11,
  .col-sm-12,
  .col-xs-1,
  .col-xs-2,
  .col-xs-3,
  .col-xs-4,
  .col-xs-5,
  .col-xs-6,
  .col-xs-7,
  .col-xs-8,
  .col-xs-9,
  .col-xs-10,
  .col-xs-11,
  .col-xs-12 {
  float: left !important;
  }

  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 !important;
    min-width: 768px;
    font-size: 2em !important;
  }
.prodname{

    }
.details{
      /*margin-left: -590px;  */
    width:80em !important;
    }

.container {
    width: auto;
    min-width: 750px;
  }

a[href]:after {
    content: none;
  }

.print-col-1
{
    float:left;
    width:30%;            
}

 .print-col-2
{
    float:right;
    width:30%;            
}
.noprint,
div.alert,
header,
.group-media,
.btn,
.footer,
.no-print,
#comments,
.nav,
ul.links.list-inline,
ul.action-links {
display:none !important;
}
.billto, .clientname , .clientphone, .date  {
    float:right;
    margin-right:9%;        
}
.billto{
    margin-top:-9%;
}

/*displays all collapsible divs expanded when printing*/
.list {
    display: inline;
}/**----x----*/
table{
    width:auto !important;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're putting the product details inside the "bill no" TD, 
A better aproach is to put product details in the next div, This is an example :

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <th>Bill No</th>
    <th>SGST</th>
    <th>CGST</th>
    <th>Total</th>
    <th>Pending</th>
    <th>Details</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>12357-2018/2019</td>
        <td>38.88</td>
        <td>8.64</td>
        <td>479.52</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>+</td>
    </tr>

    <tr style="display: none;" id="productDetails-productId">

        <td colSpan="6">

            You can put here details about product (You can put them in a table)

        </td>

    </tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with javascript, You just need to proprely apply it with js.

Comment: Tried your way, but the issue is still remains. print still looks same.

Comment: Open the page in the browser, inspect the element and copy and generated html content of the table and add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

**inspect element code:**

```
    <div class="card-body collapse in">
<div class="card-block big-font" id="print_content">
<div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" style="padding-bottom:15px;padding-top:15px;"><b>Client</b>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <br>
            <br>
            <table class="table">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <td id="c_name">qqq</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <td id="c_add">Lane B, Koregaon Park</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Contact No</th>
                        <td id="c_contact">8080808080</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Client GST</th>
                        <td id="c_gst">27AAVCJ353JE922</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Pending Amount</th>
                        <td id="c_pen">-</td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-7">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" style="padding-bottom:15px;padding-top:15px;"><b>Purchase History</b></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table" id="p_history">
                <th>Bill No</th>
                <th> SGST</th>
                <th> CGST</th>
                <th>Total</th>
                <th> Pending</th>
                <th>Details</th>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>12357-2018/2019
                            <div id="div0" class="collapse changethis">
                                <div class="panel-body" float="right" id="print_content">
                                <table class="table details" style="margin-right: -390px;margin-top:20px;" id="540">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="prodname" colspan="">Product name</th>
                                            <th>HSN Code</th>
                                            <th>Height</th>
                                            <th>Width</th>
                                            <th>Rate</th>
                                            <th>Quantity</th>

                                            <th>Amount</th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Vinyl Printing with MS Frame</td>
                                            <td>414243</td>
                                            <td>4 ft</td>
                                            <td>3 ft</td>
                                            <td>20</td>
                                            <td>3</td>
                                            <td>432</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr></tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>38.88</td>
                        <td>8.64</td>
                        <td>479.52</td>
                        <td>-</td>
                        <td><a href="#div0" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" vertical-align:="" middle;="">+</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="display: none;" id="productDetails-productId">
                        <td colspan="6">
                            <div id="div0" class="collapse changethis">
                                <div class="panel-body" float="right" id="print_content">
                                <table class="table details" style="margin-left: -390px;margin-top:20px;" id="540">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="prodname" colspan="2">Product name</th>
                                            <th>HSN Code</th>
                                            <th>Height</th>
                                            <th>Width</th>
                                            <th>Rate</th>
                                            <th>Quantity</th>
                                            <th>Amount</th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr></tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 no-print" style="text-align: center;">
<div id="printbtn" name="printbtn"> 
<br><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" onclick="print_page()"> 
<i class="icon-print4" style="color:white;"></i> Print History</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**@Mohammed Cherkaoui** : here is the inspect element code, after making changes as per your suggestion.